# start an alarm using sms keyword for android

Tags: android, alarm

sir, i don't really know how to get my code to work. it just can't start the alarm. it just starts the assigned activity and skip the alarm part. what am i doing wrong. thanks for help in advance

```
public class EAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static String sender;
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
    Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus"); 
    SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i<pdusObj.length; i++) 
    { 
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu ((byte[]) 
            pdusObj[i]); 
            sender = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
    } 

    for (SmsMessage msg : messages) {
        if (msg.getMessageBody().contains("firealert")) {

            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

            Intent i = new Intent(context, ReceiverInterface.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
                12345, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            AlarmManager am = 
                (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                    pendingIntent);
        }//end if
    }//end for

}// end onreceive
```

Answer (score 1):

The activity starting should give you a clue of what is happening. There is no point in the code that starts the activity unless the alarm is being trigger. The alarm is in fact being triggered, but as you have specified the current time (cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 0)), it triggers immediately, launching the corresponding PendingIntent. Add the desired time to the calendar in order to get the alarm to trigger in a later time.

Comment: i've tried to change the second to "10", but still doesn't alarm. why is that? should i change anything in the android manifest?

Comment: The intent i passed to the PendingIntent.getActivity() should specify the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, as stated in the API documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context, int, android.content.Intent, int). Try adding that flag and see if it is called.

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't get it. i'm a beginner in android.

Comment: oh, i've already tried some alarm tutorial codes but they also didn't work. i mean, they function well except that i can't hear any sound. could it be that it's a problem on my android phone?

Comment: The activity you're trying to start is intended to play a sound? The purpose of the AlarmManager is to schedule some event to a future time (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). Although the name starts with Alarm... it doesn't mean that it is going to play your alarm clock sound.